# Displaying Array after each Iteration

Tags: c#, arrays, forms, sorting

I am making a windows form application that sorts a list of random number by using the Gnome Sort algorithm. The Array is listed in the listbox. But what it is doing now is displaying all off the sorted Arrays in the list box. What I need it to do is display the arrays being sorted horizontally in the list box after each iteration, so that each line in the list box displays every array and the number being sorted each line.

I have tried doing it myself but I end up breaking the program each time.

Here's what I have so far:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Threading;

namespace Activity1._3
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        FillArray();
    }
    static int max = 29;
    int[] MyArray = new int[max];
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SortArray();
    }

    private void FillArray()
    {
        Random rand = new Random();
        for (int i = 0; i < max; i++)
        {
            MyArray[i] = rand.Next(100);
            listArray.Items.Add(MyArray[i] + "");
        }
    }

    private void SortArray()
    {
        int pos = 1;

        while (pos < max)
        {
            listArray.Items.Clear();
            for (int i = 0; i < max; i++)
            {
                listArray.Items.Add(MyArray[i]);
            }
            if (MyArray[pos] >= MyArray[pos - 1])
            {
                pos++;
            }
            else
            {
                SwapArray(pos);
                if (pos > 1)
                {
                    pos--;
                }
            }
        }


    }

    private void SwapArray(int pos)
    {
        int temp;
        temp = MyArray[pos];
        MyArray[pos] = MyArray[pos - 1];
        MyArray[pos - 1] = temp;
    }



}
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: By breaking the program.. What do you mean?

Comment: Whatever I try adding causes errors because I'm only a beginner in C#

Comment: Can you also provide the error message?

Comment: The program is working fine now but I still need to change the listbox as per above. It's many errors as I have tried several ways of doing it.